# I would like to get start and end of working hour by each machine per day

Tags: sql, postgresql

there is a table name events which has the time of the work of different machine, each machine per day work different hours. i would like to get the start time and end time of each machine **for each day of month**

```
    timestamp      | machine_id
---------------------+------------
 2021-11-10 12:00:14 |         24
 2021-11-10 12:10:14 |         24
 2021-11-16 07:18:44 |          9
 2021-11-16 07:21:13 |          5
 2021-11-16 07:21:14 |         11
 2021-11-15 12:30:35 |         24
 2021-11-15 12:40:35 |         24
 2021-11-15 12:50:35 |         24
 2021-11-15 13:00:35 |         24
 2021-11-15 13:10:35 |         24
 2021-11-15 13:20:35 |         24
 2021-11-15 13:30:35 |         24
 2021-11-16 07:10:59 |          5
 2021-11-16 07:11:14 |         11
 2021-11-16 07:11:13 |          5
 2021-11-16 07:11:56 |         12
 2021-11-16 07:07:47 |         21
 2021-11-16 07:08:51 |         21
 2021-11-16 07:13:44 |         22
```

Comment: can you share the table structure?

Comment: pls share table with details.

Comment: I put the table in the question, thanks

Comment: check my answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution. It takes every date and machine_id and pulls first and last timestamp for that date and machine_id.

```
with withMaxAndMin as
(
    SELECT max(timestamp) OVER(PARTITION BY machine_id, CAST (timestamp as date)
    ORDER BY CAST (timestamp as date) ASC) as endtime,
    min(timestamp) OVER(PARTITION BY machine_id, CAST (timestamp as date)
    ORDER BY CAST (timestamp as date) ASC) as starttime,
    machine_id,
    CAST (timestamp as date) as 'date',
    timestamp
    FROM #temptable
)
Select date, machine_id, starttime, endtime from withMaxAndMin group by machine_id, date, starttime, endtime
```

Comment: I have another question from you, I needed to get gps possition and engine_hour like timestamp for the fist and last value from the same table so i used over but i don't get the correct result and i have a multi rows . I dont know how to get the fist and the last value fot gps_possition and engine_hour

Comment: That would really depend on what exactly you are trying to achieve and what is composition of your data. Without seeing data and desired outcome it is quite hard to give correct answer. I woul dguess that you have different gps_position and engine_hour values for each row in table, And considering those are not incremental values oyu probably cant use `MAX` so solution would go along the ways of using `JOIN` operator to pull values out of table after you got values of starttime and endtime. But again, this is just guesswork without data to check logic. @Roro

Comment: ok great thanks, you are right it's not easy to answer without having table.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SELECT machine_id, MIN(timestamp) as starttime, MAX(timestamp) as  Endtime
FROM mach  group by machine_id ,CAST(timestamp AS DATE)
```

Here i removed machine_id from where clause, bcz you want all machine with  start and end time.

Form this you will get machine_id as 24 for 2 times , bcz when 2 dates are repeated for machine_id 24.

```
24  2021-11-10 12:00:00 2021-11-10 12:10:00
24  2021-11-15 12:31:00 2021-11-15 13:31:00
5   2021-11-16 07:11:00 2021-11-16 07:21:00
9   2021-11-16 07:19:00 2021-11-16 07:19:00
11  2021-11-16 07:11:00 2021-11-16 07:21:00
12  2021-11-16 07:12:00 2021-11-16 07:12:00
21  2021-11-16 07:08:00 2021-11-16 07:09:00
22  2021-11-16 07:14:00 2021-11-16 07:14:00
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I dont want to get for certaine machine as I did! I would like for all machine and all the days of month .

Comment: thanks but thats the min and max compare to the all the time that machine worked. I need min and max for each machine each day of month not totaly . it means for each machine i will have for example 30 days and each day there is start and end time!

Comment: check now, query updated.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT machine_id, date(timestamp) as workday, MIN(timestamp) as starttime, MAX(timestamp) as endtime
FROM events 
GROUP BY machine_id, date(timestamp)
ORDER BY machine_id, date(timestamp);
```

You need to group by machine and date both and then find min and max event time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT machine_id, DATE(timestamp) as day, MIN(timestamp) as start, MAX(timestamp) as stop
FROM events
GROUP BY machine_id, DATE(timestamp);
```

Comment: thanks but thats the min and max compare to the all the time that machine worked. I need min and max for each machine each day of month not totaly

Comment: right, added group by date